# Flutter Statusbar color not changing

Tags: flutter, dart

In my appbar I am providing the background color as Colors.white but the status bar color is still grey, whereas it is picking other colors correctly.

I don't want to change the status bar color for entire app so I am not using :

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.white));
```

My code:

```
 appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SystemUiOverlayStyle systemUiOverlayStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, 
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, 
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark); 
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(systemUiOverlayStyle);
```

[UPDATED]

What about you change the bar when you are in this page, change back when dispose:

```
      List<SystemUiOverlayStyle> uiOverlay = [
        SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
        SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
      ];
      int index = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    index = 1;
    setState(() {});
    super.dispose();
  }
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            color: uiOverlay[index%2]==SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark?Colors.white:Colors.black,
          ),
          value: uiOverlay[index],
          sized: true,
        )
         );
      }
```

Comment: this will change for the entire app, I want to change it only for specific screens

Comment: The first answer worked when I added the code in main.dart. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
AppBar(
  backwardsCompatibility: false,
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.white),
)
```

Comment: it says ```The named parameter 'backwardsCompatibility' isn't defined. ```

Comment: @ajay131 Update your flutter version. Or, try to remove that param.

Comment: I am on the latest one already, which parameter?